# Firebird unknown token 'into' when using EXECUTE STATEMENT

Tags: sql, firebird

I use EXECUTE STATEMENT to return values from select like this:

```
 EXECUTE STATEMENT 'select '||:fl||','||:f2||','||:f3||
      ' from tab1 where tab1_ID = '||:f_id
      into :v_f1,:v_f2,:v_f3;
```

When I try to execute I get  unknown token 'into' why is that and how to solve it?

Comment: Is the answer the same as given for this exact question [here](http://forums.devshed.com/showpost.php?p=2702505&postcount=2) ?

Comment: Where's the name of the table into which you're inserting? And don't you need a 'values' statement?

Comment: What is the context of execution and what is the Firebird version? Looking at http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-psql-execstat.html this should work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to use this in a procedure/trigger in Firebird 1.5, but it's just guessing. A little more detail would help.

Why use "execute statement" and not use PLSQL directly, like:

```
begin
select fl, f2, f3 from tab1 where tab1_ID = :f_id into :v_f1,:v_f2,:v_f3;
end
```

assuming you previously declare f_id, v_f1, v_f2, v_f3 as variables or parameters.